# Best way to get the Original Target

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, delegates

What's a jQuery like and/or best practices way of getting the original target of an event in jQuery (or in browser javascript in general).

I've been using something like this

```
$('body').bind('click', function(e){
        //depending on the browser, either srcElement or 
        //originalTarget will be populated with the first
        //element that intercepted the click before it bubbled up
        var originalElement = e.srcElement;
        if(!originalElement){originalElement=e.originalTarget;}                         
});
```

which works, but I'm not pleased with the two line feature sniffing.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Stumbled on this old question wondering why **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4816990/2407212)** with only one third as many votes as the accepted answer seems so very very much better to me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it in one line with `var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;` but it ain't pretty JQuery-like ;-)

[Edit: But according to http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.target `event.target` might do...]

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing jQuery should be abstracting?  I'm really surprised at this.

Comment: I remember trying e.target a while back running into problems with it.  It looks like they've since been fixed (or else I've been fixed since a while back). Also, fancy termination tricks read like two lines to me ;)

Comment: As of 2022, `e.srcElement` is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement)

Answer (score 24):

I believe e.target is what you require

```
$('body').bind('click', function(e){
                e.target // the original target
                e.target.id // the id of the original target                                               
});
```

If you go to the [jQuery in Action website](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) and download the source code, take a look at

- **Chapter 4 -** dom.2.propagation.html

which deals with event propagation with bubble and capture handlers

Answer (score 22):

Using `event.originalTarget` can cause "Permission denied to access property 'XYZ' from a non-chrome context" -error, so i'd recommend using following:

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
```

`event.target` works on Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari.

Comment: +1: This is the only version which worked for me cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

In conjunction with [How to detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) here is how you might trap a sub-widget with similar hide-when-clicked-outside functionality to prevent your own pop-over from hiding along with it; in this case, we are trapping the JQuery UI Datepicker pop-over widget:

```
// not using jquery .one handler for this, so we can persist outside click later
$('html').click(function(evt) {
    // just return if element has the datepicker as a parent
    if ($(evt.target).parents('#ui-datepicker-div').length>0) return;

    //toggle shut our widget pop-over
    $('#mywidget').toggle();

    // now, unbind this event since our widget is closed:
    $(this).unbind(evt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in normal Javascript, var t = (e.originalTarget)?e.originalTarget:e.srcElement; should be enough to read it across all browsers.

Comment: This is the same as `var t = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;` (only longer!)