# Check new hover target after hover out (Javascript/JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

What is the most neatest way to check whether a user is hovering over an object after hovering out of a different object. I.e. If user mouses out of object A onto object B, how would you suggest I go about monitoring this? I don't really like the idea of continously monitoring the mouses position when it moves, though it may be the only option...

Comment: Add a hover event to object B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aVz7Q/4/

A simple hover event in jQuery can accomplish this, with the help of some variable work, you can store what the previous element and current element are.

Answer (score 1):

Events bubble up. Add en event listener for the parent element of A & B. In that listener you can record on mouseout the original target of the event as the latest object that was mousedout (using something like $(this).data("latestMouseout",latestTarget), [Best way to get the Original Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485453/best-way-to-get-the-original-target)). On mousein, you can check your conditions and see if latest mouseout target and mousein target meet the conditions you need.

I know this is a little vague, but so is your question. If this helps great. If not, feel free to ask clarifying questions.