# Finding the source of a click in event bubbling

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I have the following code:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="btn1">1</button>
    <button id="btn2">2</button>
</div>
```

I attach an event handler to the `<div>` to handle clicks.

When I click a button, the event is captured by the div.  Is there a way to get the source of the event?

For example, if the event were on each of the the buttons then the `this` keyword would refer to the buttons.  When it's on the `<div>` it refers to that.

When the click is caught by the div, is there a way to locate the source of the click?  i.e. which actual button was clicked?

Thanks all

Dave

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485453/best-way-to-get-the-original-target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `originalTarget` property of the `event` object to find out the source of the event.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwZwL/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="btn1">1</button>
    <button id="btn2">2</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('buttons').onclick = function (evt) {
    var source = evt.srcElement || evt.originalTarget
    alert(source.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, this should help:

```
$("#buttons").click(function(evt){
       alert($(evt.target).attr("id"));
});
```